# How to test USB stick speed?

Tags: usb, performance, dd

I have a USB stick I'm trying to measure the read and write speed on.  I'm having trouble deciding whether I should write random data or zeros, and how much.  I want to do this as fast as possible, but avoid artificially high reported speeds due to caching in the operating system.  Here's my procedure so far:

#### Measure write speed

```
# Partition on the device under test
DEVICE=/dev/sdd5
WRITE_DATA=/tmp/write_data
READ_DATA=/tmp/read_data
BLOCK_COUNT=20
BLOCK_SIZE=524288

# Create a random test file to ensure data integrity.
dd if=/dev/urandom of=${WRITE_DATA} bs=${BLOCK_SIZE} count=${BLOCK_COUNT}

# Deactivate the cache.
hdparm -W0 ${DEVICE}

# Write.
dd if=${WRITE_DATA} of=${DEVICE} bs=${BLOCK_SIZE} count=${BLOCK_COUNT} oflag=direct
```

#### Measure read speed

```
# Cause the kernel to drop clean caches.
# See also: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

# Read.
dd if=${DEVICE} of=${READ_DATA} bs=${BLOCK_SIZE} count=${BLOCK_COUNT} oflag=direct

# Make sure we read back what we wrote.
cmp --silent ${WRITE_DATA} ${READ_DATA} || echo "Files are different."

# Cleanup.
rm ${WRITE_DATA} ${READ_DATA}
```

USB stick size: 128 GiB

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Questions:

1. What is a 'large enough' size to dodge OS optimizations and noise in the result?  Does this depend on my OS or USB stick size?
2. Does the contents of the data that I write/read back matter?  Does the USB stick optimize if I accidentally attempt to loopback something that's already in the memory (e.g. all 0's or 1's)?

Comment: Be careful: if you hit it with physical writes too much too quickly, it will die sooner.

Comment: Understanding what kind of errors come up when it's starting to fail could be useful, too.  How do you detect bad USB sticks if not by this process?